# AppInviteDialog not working in Android Facebook SDK 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

After long research and trying to fix this on my own, I haven't found any acceptable working result.

Following [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) I'm trying to invite friends to my app. All elements, such as share buttons are working properly.

The only problem are with "Invite to app" dialog. After selecting a friend, the dialog are showing red alert icon and "send" button is turns into "retry" button.

I have tried fix this in many ways - configure my app in [FB dev page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) (like changing app category: game, travel .etc), adding new permission for sharing (but I haven't found, that inviting is required it), using [GamesRequests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.3) (but my app isn't a game, it's android + canvas app). So I have returned again to AppInviteDialog.

Also, I have trying to use own instance of it, with listeners, instead of static class.

```
inviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(this);
inviteDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Result result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MainACtivity, InviteCallback - SUCCESS!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.i(TAG, "MainACtivity, InviteCallback - CANCEL!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MainACtivity, InviteCallback - ERROR! " + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

And calling it, like in [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android):

```
 if(AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
            .setApplinkUrl(appUrl)
            .setPreviewImageUrl(imagePreviewUrl)
            .build();
            //AppInviteDialog.show(this, content); //static
        inviteDialog.show(content); //my instance
  }
```

But all what i get is:

[image]

## Edit:

After creating link to my app using [AppLinks](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host), and using it in the AppInviteDialog, now all works fine.
It's a bit confusing, that in [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) not clearly described, what kind of link need to use: "AppLinks link" or just "app link (link to your fb app)".

Comment: Hey Vadym, did you get that Callback to work? I'm not getting anything back after I invite people.

Comment: @KarimVarela if you are mean `FacebookCallback<Result>` from my code snippet, yes, it works - I can show success message, or handle error.

Comment: Do you know how to get the selected friends id? As far as I know this version removed the ability to get them.

Comment: @Proverbio, no, I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an error message?

I get this if I don't use an AppLink.

https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1374389166202673/?platform=app-links-host

Comment: There aren't any errors. I've tried to get any messages, so at least find out what is happening, and why the red alert sign appears. But not from log, nor from listener, there are no error messages.  

I'm not using AppLinks. And even didn't touch it's settings at all.

Comment: Actually, I don't need AppLink functional. I just need send to user Invite to my app [like this](http://papers.traustikristjansson.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/CandyCruchInvite_censored.jpg). The only way, that I've found from SDK 4.0 documentation is AppInviteDialog.


But thanks for answer, I will try to search in this way tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have send me in the right way! It's a bit confusing, that in documentation not clearly described, what kind of link need to use: "AppLinks link" or just "app link (link to your fb app)". This just creates misunderstood, and confusion to developers.       
I have configured my AppLink URL by your link, that just redirect to my FB app page, and added it to AppInviteDialog. Now all is working fine.

Comment: I agree, it was very frustrating one afternoon for me as well.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and my cause was not calling `onActivityResult` on the facebook CallbackManager. This is how I fixed it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    facebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    // ...
}
```

Then here is where I was having the error:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // This is the line I was lacking
    facebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

After onActivityResult was added, I am getting my callbacks fired:

```
AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
FacebookCallback callback =  new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        }
    };
appInviteDialog.registerCallback(facebookCallbackManager, callback);
appInviteDialog.show(content);
```